# how to use xslt 2.0 in visual studio 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, xslt, .net-4.0, xslt-2.0

I am using xslt 2.0 for transforming one xml format to another xml format.But Visual Studio 2010 supports only xslt1.0.

So, I referred the stackoverflow link and followed the procedure they said.But it did not working for me...

http://zeetalks.wordpress.com/2011/07/26/vs2010-adding-xslt-to-visual-studio-2010/

[XSLT 2.0 intellisense in Visual Studio 2010 - Adding a schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116854/xslt-2-0-intellisense-in-visual-studio-2010-adding-a-schema)

When i opening my xslt 2.0 xsl file in VS-2010 then it raised following 5 Errors.They are...

1. xpath-default-namespace is not yet implemented
2. xsl:function is not yet implemented
3. xsl:param/@as is not yet implemented
4. xsl:for-each-group is not yet implemented
5. xsl:sequence is not yet implemetented

---

Thanks for your cooperation... I found a link from [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24766/Using-Saxon-XSL-2-0-and-XQuery-1-0-in-NET#_rating). for use xslt2.0 in .net framework.Now i am looking for a good xslt IDE for my development. Once again thanks to all...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You *can* add XSLT 2.0 intellisence to Visual Studio, as described in the provided links.

**However, Visual Studio (from 2005 up) is tightly integrated with the standard .NET XSLT 1.0 processor XslCompiledTransform -- and the Visual Studio XSLT Debugger and execution subsystem only works with this XSLT processor**.

As for Altova's VS Integrated Package, I have never used it and wouldn't be surprized that in the past it was working as described, but stopped working after one of the VS 2010 updates / service packs. My guess is that you haven't bought/installed this package.

**I would recommend using an XSLT IDE that is especially designed to support XSLT 2.0** -- one such tool is **[oXygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/xslt_editor.html)** and there are a number of others people have been using, such as **[Stylus Studio](http://www.stylusstudio.com/xml_download.html?gclid=CKfF8J3067ACFSQbQgodryOWuQ)**.

Comment: Or indeed XML spy. XMLSpy does do the embedded window in Visual studio (at a high cost), and an XSLT 2.0 processor (processor only), but then if you had that, you might as well use it. I would also recommend oXygen, their customer support is excelent, and althouh XML spy has the better XML navigation and display, oXygen is very flexible, and once you get past the eclipse-ness, pretty good.

Comment: @Woody: Are you the person who asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133092/how-do-you-identify-duplicate-values-in-a-numerical-sequence-using-xpath-2-0 ?

Comment: no, that is an imposter, I joined in 2010. Plus that is a really simple question!

Comment: @Woody: He isn't an imposter -- just left SO long ago before you joined. As for the question, it isn't easy to provide an ellegant solution to it -- therefore it is a nice question.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev : I have developing asp.net web application.So,One of the functionalities of web application is transform one xml to another xml at runtime.So,Suppose i will choose seperate xslt IDE then how will i run with as part of my web application...

Comment: @Saravanan: If you mean how to perform an XSLT 2.0 transformation, this is described in the documentation of the XSLT 2.0 processor that you will choose to use -- respectively Saxon.NET, XMLPrime or Altova. For Saxon.NET, additionally there are code samples coming with the installation of the product -- probably the other two products also offer such code samples.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev:i have downloaded the Saxon.NET Package.It contains only Saxon.NET.dll,Transform.exe,Compile.exe.So, Do i need to inlcude the reference of the dll file.My Problem is , I have One Button named doConversion.So, When i click the button,i want to do the xslt transformation.How do i use it?

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev:thanks for your cooperation.I found a way to use xslt 2.0 in .net framwork and also posted as a answer...

Comment: @Saravanan: Yes, one can use such existing project, but I strongly recommend checking the documentation of the XSLT 2.0 processor you have chosen (it seems to be Saxon.NET in your case). Processor functionality typically change from version to version, so what used to work 3-4 versions ago may no longer work with the latest version, or the latest version may offer a new, more attractive and superior way of doing something. Just go to http://www.saxonica.com and read the documentation of Saxon.NET. Also study the "samples" directory which the installation created on your computer.