# Using XSLT to transform one xml format into another

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have the following xml input file, and would like to transform it into a different xml schema format.
So far what I have is working and producing a well-formatted xml output.

Two challenges:

1. I would like to structure my XSLT a little better where I would be using multiple `<xsl:apply-templates/>` commands.
2. I'm also going to process several `<tradeType>` nodes (i.e. `<tradeType>IRS</tradeType>`, as well as `<tradeType>CDS</tradeType>` ), and would need my output to be be slightly different based on that `<tradeType>` value.

Here's an input sample for `<tradeType>IRS</tradeType>` :

```
<collection>
    <Trades_Output>
        <tradeId>IRS-002</tradeId>
        <tradeDate>2007-09-05</tradeDate>
        <tradeType>IRS</tradeType>
        <buySell>BUY</buySell>
        <counterparty>COUNTERPARTY IRS</counterparty>
        <internalUnit>My Company Inc</internalUnit>
        <legOnePayerPartyReference>COUNTERPARTY IRS</legOnePayerPartyReference>
        <legOneReceiverPartyReference>My Company Inc</legOneReceiverPartyReference>
        <legOneStartDate>2007-09-05</legOneStartDate>
        <legOneEndDate>2014-09-05</legOneEndDate>
        <legOneNotional>151521500</legOneNotional>
        <legOneCurrency>GBP</legOneCurrency>
        <legOneRateIndex>LIBOR</legOneRateIndex>
        <legOneSpread>0.0022</legOneSpread>
        <legOneFixedRate></legOneFixedRate>
        <legTwoPayerPartyReference>My Company Inc</legTwoPayerPartyReference>
        <legTwoReceiverPartyReference>COUNTERPARTY IRS</legTwoReceiverPartyReference>
        <legTwoStartDate>2007-09-05</legTwoStartDate>
        <legTwoEndDate>2014-09-05</legTwoEndDate>
        <legTwoNotional>151521500</legTwoNotional>  
        <legTwoCurrency>GBP</legTwoCurrency>
        <legTwoRateIndex></legTwoRateIndex>
        <legTwoSpread></legTwoSpread>
        <legTwoFixedRate>0.04575</legTwoFixedRate>
        <legTwoRateType>FIXED</legTwoRateType>
    </Trades_Output>
    <Trades_Output>
       <tradeId>CDS-002</tradeId>
       <tradeDate>2010-09-27</tradeDate>
       <tradeType>CDS</tradeType>
       <counterparty>COUNTERPARTY CDS</counterparty>
        <internalUnit>My Company Limited</internalUnit>
       <buySell>BUY</buySell>
       <status>OPEN</status>
       <startDate>2007-09-05</startDate>
       <endDate>2014-09-05</endDate>
       <sellerPartyReference>COUNTERPARTY IRS</sellerPartyReference>
       <buyerPartyReference>My Company Inc</buyerPartyReference>
       <instrumentId>RBS (REG) 01/08/2013</instrumentId>
       <currency>GBP</currency>
       <amount>75000000</amount>
       <fixedRate>0.0098</fixedRate>
       <dayCountFraction>ACT/360</dayCountFraction>
     </Trades_Output>
</collection>
```

My desired output:

```
 <deal>
 <dealHeader>
      <dealId>IRS-RRT-002</dealId>
      <dealType>IRS</dealType>
      <dealDate>2007-09-05</dealDate>
      <status>OPEN</status>
 </dealHeader>
 <trade>
    <sysId>2</sysId>
    <tradeHeader>
        <tradeId>IRS-RRT-002</tradeId>
        <tradeDate>2007-09-05</tradeDate>
        <tradeType>IRS</tradeType>
        <counterparty>COUNTERPARTY IRS</counterparty>
        <internalUnit>My Company Inc</internalUnit>
        <buySell>BUY</buySell>
        <status>OPEN</status>
    </tradeHeader>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <name>OrigID</name>
            <value>IRS-RRT-002</value>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
    <product>
        <swap>
            <swapStream>
                <payerPartyReference href='COUNTERPARTY IRS'/>
                <receiverPartyReference href='My Company Inc'/>
                <calculationPeriodDates id='CalcPeriodDates0'>
                    <effectiveDate>
                        <unadjustedDate>2007-09-05</unadjustedDate>
                        <dateAdjustments>
                            <businessDayConvention>MODFOLLOWING</businessDayConvention>
                        </dateAdjustments>
                    </effectiveDate>
                    <terminationDate>
                        <unadjustedDate>2014-09-05</unadjustedDate>
                        <dateAdjustments>
                            <businessDayConvention>MODFOLLOWING</businessDayConvention>
                        </dateAdjustments>
                    </terminationDate>
                    <calculationPeriodDatesAdjustments>
                        <businessDayConvention>MODFOLLOWING</businessDayConvention>
                    </calculationPeriodDatesAdjustments>
                    <calculationPeriodFrequency>
                        <periodMultiplier>6</periodMultiplier>
                        <period>M</period>
                        <rollConvention>NONE</rollConvention>
                    </calculationPeriodFrequency>
                </calculationPeriodDates>
                <paymentDates>
                    <calculationPeriodDatesReference href='#CalcPeriodDates0'/>
                    <paymentFrequency>
                        <periodMultiplier>6</periodMultiplier>
                        <period>M</period>
                    </paymentFrequency>
                    <payRelativeTo>CalculationPeriodEndDate</payRelativeTo>
                    <paymentDatesAdjustments>
                        <businessDayConvention>MODFOLLOWING</businessDayConvention>
                    </paymentDatesAdjustments>
                </paymentDates>
                <calculationPeriodAmount>
                    <calculation>
                        <notionalSchedule>
                            <notionalStepSchedule>
                                <initialValue>151521500</initialValue>
                                <currency>GBP</currency>
                            </notionalStepSchedule>
                        </notionalSchedule>
                        <floatingRateCalculation>
                            <floatingRateIndex>LIBOR</floatingRateIndex>
                            <indexTenor>
                                <periodMultiplier>6</periodMultiplier>
                                <period>M</period>
                            </indexTenor>
                            <spreadSchedule>
                                <initialValue>0</initialValue>
                            </spreadSchedule>
                        </floatingRateCalculation>
                        <dayCountFraction>Act/360</dayCountFraction>
                    </calculation>
                </calculationPeriodAmount>
                <stubCalculationPeriodAmount>
                    <finalStub/>
                </stubCalculationPeriodAmount>
                <principalExchanges>
                    <initialExchange>false</initialExchange>
                    <finalExchange>false</finalExchange>
                    <intermediateExchange>false</intermediateExchange>
                </principalExchanges>
            </swapStream>
            <swapStream>
                <payerPartyReference href='My Company Inc'/>
                <receiverPartyReference href='COUNTERPARTY IRS'/>
                <calculationPeriodDates id='CalcPeriodDates0'>
                    <effectiveDate>
                        <unadjustedDate>2007-09-05</unadjustedDate>
                        <dateAdjustments>
                            <businessDayConvention>MODFOLLOWING</businessDayConvention>
                        </dateAdjustments>
                    </effectiveDate>
                    <terminationDate>
                        <unadjustedDate>2014-09-05</unadjustedDate>
                        <dateAdjustments>
                            <businessDayConvention>MODFOLLOWING</businessDayConvention>
                        </dateAdjustments>
                    </terminationDate>
                    <calculationPeriodDatesAdjustments>
                        <businessDayConvention>MODFOLLOWING</businessDayConvention>
                    </calculationPeriodDatesAdjustments>
                    <calculationPeriodFrequency>
                        <periodMultiplier>6</periodMultiplier>
                        <period>M</period>
                        <rollConvention>NONE</rollConvention>
                    </calculationPeriodFrequency>
                </calculationPeriodDates>
                <paymentDates>
                    <calculationPeriodDatesReference href='#CalcPeriodDates0'/>
                    <paymentFrequency>
                        <periodMultiplier>6</periodMultiplier>
                        <period>M</period>
                    </paymentFrequency>
                    <payRelativeTo>CalculationPeriodEndDate</payRelativeTo>
                    <paymentDatesAdjustments>
                        <businessDayConvention>MODFOLLOWING</businessDayConvention>
                    </paymentDatesAdjustments>
                </paymentDates>
                <calculationPeriodAmount>
                    <calculation>
                        <notionalSchedule>
                            <notionalStepSchedule>
                                <initialValue>151521500</initialValue>
                                <currency>GBP</currency>
                            </notionalStepSchedule>
                        </notionalSchedule>
                        <fixedRateSchedule>
                            <initialValue>0.04575</initialValue>
                        </fixedRateSchedule>
                        <dayCountFraction>Act/360</dayCountFraction>
                    </calculation>
                </calculationPeriodAmount>
                <principalExchanges>
                    <initialExchange>false</initialExchange>
                    <finalExchange>false</finalExchange>
                    <intermediateExchange>false</intermediateExchange>
                </principalExchanges>
            </swapStream>
        </swap>
    </product>
  </trade>
 </deal>
```

and a snippet of my XSLT code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <body>
            <insertions>          
                <xsl:apply-templates/>          
            </insertions>
        </body>
    </xsl:template>     
    <xsl:template match="Trades_Output">
        <trade>
            <tradeHeader>
                <tradeId>
                    <xsl:value-of select="tradeId"/>
                </tradeId>
                <tradeDate>
                    <xsl:value-of select="tradeDate"/>
                </tradeDate>
            </tradeHeader>
            <product>
                <swap>
                    <swapStream>
                        <payerPartyReference>
                            <xsl:value-of select="legOnePayerPartyReference"/>
                        </payerPartyReference>
                        <receiverPartyReference>
                            <xsl:value-of select="legOneReceiverPartyReference"/>
                        </receiverPartyReference>
                    </swapStream>
                    <swapStream>
                        <payerPartyReference>
                            <xsl:value-of select="legTwoPayerPartyReference"/>
                        </payerPartyReference>
                        <receiverPartyReference>
                            <xsl:value-of select="legTwoReceiverPartyReference"/>
                        </receiverPartyReference>                
                    </swapStream>
                </swap>
            </product>
        </trade>
    </xsl:template>
....
```

Is there any additional advice one can provide to structure my XSLT a little better? In other words, as opposed to having all xml output within `<xsl:template match="Trades_Output">`

thank you.
Bob

Comment: Maybe I am misreading the question, but I can't see what your XML input is and your desired XML output. Could you rephrase your question and provide: a) An complete XML input. b) An complete desired output. c) Some description between the input and output. d) What you have tried so far.

Comment: My main challenge now is that I'll be processing two different values for <tradeType> - "IRS" and "CDS". The xml output will vary depending on the <tradeType> element value. Will I be using <xsl:if > ?

Comment: I edited my original post. Hopefully clearer. thank you much .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*1. I would like to structure my XSLT a little better where I would be using multiple  commands.*

The design of the source XML is pretty bad, this would be a lot better if the elements were like:

```
<PayerPartyReference leg="one"/>
```

Since all the LegOne/LegTwo elements seem to be basically the same, however you using XSLT 2.0 so there's a solution to that using regex, I'd do something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <body>
        <insertions>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Trades_Output"/>
        </insertions>
    </body>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Trades_Output">
    <trade>
        <tradeHeader>
            <xsl:copy-of select="tradeId | tradeDate"/>
        </tradeHeader>
        <product>
            <swap>
                <!-- this will generate two groups for the elements starting with legOne/legTwo -->
                <xsl:for-each-group select="*[matches(name(),'(legOne|legTwo)')]"
                    group-by="substring(name(),1,6)">
                    <swapStream>
                        <!-- 
                          this will apply to legOnePayerPartyReference and legOneReceiverPartyReference
                          when in group legOne and respectively when in group legTwo 
                        -->
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[ends-with(name(),'PartyReference')]"/>
                        <calculationPeriodDates>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[ends-with(name(),'Date')]"/>
                        </calculationPeriodDates>
                    </swapStream>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </swap>
        </product>
    </trade>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[matches(name(),'(legOne|legTwo)PayerPartyReference')]">
    <payerPartyReference href="{.}"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[matches(name(),'(legOne|legTwo)ReceiverPartyReference')]">
    <receiverPartyReference href="{.}"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[matches(name(),'(legOne|legTwo)StartDate')]">
    <effectiveDate>
        <unadjustedDate>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </unadjustedDate>
        <dateAdjustments>
            <businessDayConvention>MODFOLLOWING</businessDayConvention>
        </dateAdjustments>
    </effectiveDate>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[matches(name(),'(legOne|legTwo)EndDate')]">
    <terminationDate>
        <unadjustedDate>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </unadjustedDate>
        <dateAdjustments>
            <businessDayConvention>MODFOLLOWING</businessDayConvention>
        </dateAdjustments>
    </terminationDate>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It's unclear to me were most of the stuff in your desired Output comes from, I'm guessing lot's of it is fixed...however this should get you started.

---

*I'm also going to process several `<tradeType>` nodes (i.e. `<tradeType>IRS</tradeType>`, as well as `<tradeType>CDS</tradeType>` ), and would need my output to be be slightly different based on that `<tradeType>` value.*

This totally depends on what you mean by *slightly* so maybe provide some more info here on what would be different for each tradeType... the simplest solutin would be to just have one template per tradeType

```
<xsl:template match="Trades_Output[tradeType='IRS']">
```

respectively

```
<xsl:template match="Trades_Output[tradeType='CDS']">
```

and then have different structures in there...

Comment: this is great advice and I find it quite helpful. I've added select="Trades_Output" to my initial "apply-templates" tag, and I already have two separate <xsl:template> sections I've implemented - one for <tradeType>IRS</tradeType> and another for <tradeType>CDS</tradeType>.

Comment: and so for clarity, by having two separate templates (<xsl:template match="..."), the XSL code will flow sequentially and process both templates ?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I just updated my desired xml output to now include a <deal> node wrapped around the entire <trade> parent node. I also included a new <dealHeader> section, whose children are also a copy of <tradeId> | <tradeDate | etc. How can I use the <xsl:Copy> and change the element names while maintaining the same element values ?

Comment: How is your input file structured when you have multiple trades? Will you have multiple Trade_Output? If not that changes things a bit. Maybe update your source example with more than one tradeType...

Comment: xsl:for-each-group is causing an exception in Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: if you are using visual studio you cannot use XSLT-2.0, the .net xslt processor does not support it... can you use another xslt processor like saxon?

Comment: I've included <Trades_Output><tradeType>CDS</tradeType> node as well. This way you can see that there are indeed mult <Trades_Output> nodes.

Comment: someone suggested downloading into VS 2012 the xslt 2.0 XSD from w3c. Here's the post I just read: http://appdevonsharepoint.com/adding-xslt-2-0-intellisense-to-visual-studio/

Comment: Installing the intellisense for xslt 2.0 will not solve your problem, visual studio will still not be able to do an XSLT 2.0 transformation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205268/how-to-use-xslt-2-0-in-visual-studio-2010 the link is for VS 2010 but this is still the case for VS 2012